# Angular directive instead of ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have following code:

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('directiveA', function () {
          return {
            templateUrl: '/template-a.html'
          };
        }
    )
    .directive('directiveB', function () {
          return {
            templateUrl: '/template-b.html'
          };
        }
    )
    .directive(// I hope you got the point.
```

That code is not very DRY, and I'd prefer to use `ng-include`, but those directives are very nice, like footer, header, flash-messages, etc. and allow to write very readable HTML, so probably it is better to have them.

Could I somehow add to angular.module additional method, something like `viewDirective`, to describe directives in this way:

```
angular.module('app')
    .viewDirective('directiveA', '/template-a.html')
    .viewDirective('directiveB', '/template-b.html')
    ...
```

Could I add it to `angular.module.prototype`, or is there better way to expand module methods? Is something like that already implemented in angular, so I don't invent the wheel? Or is it better to use `ng-include`?

Comment: Why don't you create a directive factory to do it?

Comment: If you need logic with your views, I would go for ui-router. At least for the header/content/footer etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep your directive name and path convention, you can do the following:

```
var directiveNames = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
_.forEach(directiveNames, function (name) {
    angular.module('app').directive(name, function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: '/' + name + '.html'
        }
    )
 });
```

You can find references to angular itself creating their own directives with DRY principles programmatically here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d077966ff1ac18262f4615ff1a533db24d4432a7/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js
(line 49)

Comment: Nice, thanks for the links to source. 

So, I don't need method chaining on module? Probably then I could implement `viewDirective(module, directive, template)` as a function, not a method of module. And yes, loops are also the good way to make it more DRY.

Comment: Yeah you could do that if you think it looks better or if you had a reason to reuse viewDirective for any reason. Also, angular module doesn't have to be chained. If you look at big projects with many files, each usually begins with `angular.module(x)...`.

Comment: Ok,  7 directives written simpler, -23 lines of code saved. Looks like not much, but still feels nice, thanks. :)